# Como puedo paginar una tabla que esta en un Modal

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema no puedo paginar una tabla que se encuentra en un Modal les adjunto el codigo del modal que contiene la consulta a la BD Si alguien puede darme una idea ..he visto unos ejemplos en la web pero no se aplican a la tabla en el modal...Desde ya muchas gracias

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="AgregarPro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">



<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">                                              
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtrar" placeholder="Buscar productos" >
</div>
<a href="#" id="bus"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar</a>
              </div>
              </form>




                                  <?php
                                    require_once('data/conexion.php');
                                    $sql = "select * from productos where id_area = '$id_area'";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                  ?>       

                                    <table id= "sampleTable" class="table">

                                    <tr  class="warning">
                                        <th>Código</th>
                                        <th>Producto</th>
                                        <th>Marca</th>  
                                        <th><span class="pull-right">Stock </span></th>
                                        <th><span class="pull-right">Cantidad</span></th>
                                        <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px; ">Agregar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        $codigo=$row['id_producto'];
                                        $producto=$row['name'];
                                        $marca=$row['marca'];
                                        $stock=$row['stock_actual'];
                                        $cantidad=$row['precio_unidad'];                                            
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $marca; ?></td>
                                        <td class='col-xs-1'>
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $codigo ?>" value="<?php echo $stock ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class='col-xs-2'>
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <input type="number"  min="0" max="<?php echo $stock ?>"  class="form-control" name= "cants" id="cants<?php echo $codigo ?>" style="width: 80px;" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
   <td ><a class='btn btn-info' style="" href="#" style="" onclick="agregar(<?php echo $codigo ?>, $('#cants').val(), $('#receptor_sal').val(),  $('#dest_sal').val(), $('#idarea').val(), $('#iduser').val(), $('#comment').val() )"><i class="fas fa-plus" style=""></i></a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php    
                                    }               
                                    ?>



                                    </table>




          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button> 



          </div>
```

Comment: Perdon queria agregar que no me toma los controles datatable no se porque en el Modal no puedo cargar las librerias. y he probado de todo

Comment: Gracias a todos por observar la pregunta ...lo pude solucionar con los controles datatables...Muchas gracias!!!!